# Two Telegram messengers in the Unity Launcher

Tags: telegram

I installed Telegram Messenger from source, but now there are Telegram and Telegram Desktop in the Unity Launcher. Has someone any clue how to remove one of these?

Comment: What do you mean by Launchpad? This? https://launchpad.net/ if so, what does it have to do with what you installed? If not, can you clarify?

Comment: Most likely, you started the first time from cli and locked it to the launcher, right?

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, Telegram makes two `.desktop` files when installed; one in `/usr/share/applications` and one in `~/.local/share/applications`

I now just rename the local one so that it isn't read:

```
mv ~/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/telegram
```

This immediately kills the second icon.

You may have to repeat when Telegram updates itself, as it will regenerate the file

Comment: I wouldn't suggest him to remove the global one, if it exists, nor to edit it! First copy locally before editing!

Answer (score 2):

Right click the unwanted one and choose unlock from launcher. This approach will remove it from the launcher but should be risk free and doesn't require editing anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that whenever you launch the Telegram Desktop app, it will automatically generate the file `org.telegram.desktop._<some_id>.desktop` under the `~/.local/share/applications` folder. Note that the one in `/usr/share/applications` will have the root privilege to generate that file.

There's a Linux feature called "immutable bit" provided by the `chattr` command, which can be used to make a file unable to be deleted, even by root. So here are the steps to stop the auto-creation of that duplicated launcher:

1. Open the file `org.telegram.desktop._<some_id>.desktop` which is under `~/.local/share/applications`, delete all its contents.
2. Set the immutable bit on that file:

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.local/share/applications/org.telegram.desktop._<some_id>.desktop
```

3. Start the Telegram Desktop app, now it will not be able to create or rewrite the duplicated launcher.